# How to install Postgres on Synology via iPKG

Tags: linux, postgresql, synology

I own a Synology DS214SE (just as ref) and I would like to install a Postgres instance through the package iPKG.

I have looked at everything Google made available to me and I couldn't find something that actually worked.

Background:
Synology comes with a postgres 9.2, unfortunately it appears that is for internal used and it's no recommended to use it. Therefore the way to go is to install another instance of postgres via a Synology supported source.

I was able to do with no problem (PS v8.2). What I do not understand is how to properly configure it. Anyone offering some knowledge about this will be definitely rewarded in afterlife and brought to fame on every corner of the WWW!

thx!
;mE

Comment: I have a 412+ did you ever get postgres working?

Comment: Yes. I documented it here. http://iamsensoria.com/post/130235198606/postgres-on-synology

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figure it out and documented it here.
https://www.iamsensoria.com/2015/09/postgres-on-synology.html